# Semi-Distinct MySQL Query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table called `items` that contains thousands of records. Each record has a `user_id` field and a `created` (datetime) field.

Trying to put together a query to `SELECT` 25 rows, passing a string of user ids as a condition and sorted by `created DESC`.

In some cases, there might be just a few user ids, while in other instances, there may be hundreds.

If the result set is greater than 25, I want to pare it down by eliminating duplicate `user_id` records. For instance, if there were two records for `user_id = 3`, only the most recent (according to `created` datetime) would be included.

In my attempts at a solution, I am having trouble because while, for example, it's easy to get a result set of 100 (allowing duplicate `user_id` records), or a result set of 16 (using `GROUP BY` for unique `user_id` records), it's hard to get 25.

One logical approach, which may not be the correct MySQL approach, is to get the most recent record for each for each `user_id`, and then, if the result set is less than 25, begin adding a second record for each `user_id` until the 25 record limit is met (maybe a third, fourth, etc. record for each `user_id` would be needed).

Can this be accomplished with a MySQL query, or will I need to take a large result set and trim it down to 25 with code?

Comment: What is the requirement of removing the duplicates. Lets say you have recordset of 35(with dups), but removing dups results in 23. Which ids will be allowed to dup in order to have 25 records?

Comment: The most recently created records, irrespective of user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you're trying to accomplish is possible as a SQL query.  Your desire is to return 25 rows, no matter what the normal data groupings are whereas SQL is usually picky about returning based on data groupings.

If you want a purely MySQL-based solution, you may be able to accomplish this with a stored procedure.  (Supported in MySQL 5.0.x and later.)  However, it might just make more sense to run the query to return all 100+ rows and then trim it programmatically within the application.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the most recent for each user --

> SELECT user_id, create
>       FROM items AS i1
>       LEFT JOIN items AS i2
>           ON i1.user_id = i2.user_id AND i1.create > i2.create
>       WHERE i2.id IS NULL

his will get you the most recent two records for each user --

> SELECT user_id, create
>       FROM items AS i1
>       LEFT JOIN items AS i2
>           ON i1.user_id = i2.user_id AND i1.create > i2.create
>       LEFT JOIN items IS i3
>           ON i2.user_id = i3.user_id AND i2.create > i3.create
>       WHERE i3.id IS NULL

Try working from there.

You could nicely put this into a stored procedure.

Comment: Ahh, gold ol' vim and its digraphs. :)

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is to use application logic, as this is very much application layer logic you are trying to implement at the DB level, i.e. filtering down the results to make the search more useful to the end user.

You could implement a stored procedure (personally I would never do such a thing) or just get the application to decide which 25 results.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to get the most recent item from each user, followed by the most recent items from all users, and limit that.  You could construct pathological examples where this probably isn't what you want, but it should be pretty good in general.

Comment: That's a good simple solution. I can select one from all users, and if it's less than 25, fill in the gap by taking the most recent overall with no regard for dupe users.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way :(   I had to do something similar when I built a report for my company that would pull up customer disables that were logged in a database.  Only problem was that the disconnect is ran and logged every 30 minutes.  Therefore, the rows would not be distinct since the timestamp was different in every disconnect.  I solved this problem with sub queries.  I don't have the exact code anymore, but I beleive this is how I implemented it:

```
SELECT CORP, HOUSE, CUST, 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 hsd
        FROM #TempTable t2
        WHERE t1.corp = t2.corp
        AND t1.house = t2.house
        AND t1.cust = t2.cust
    ) DisableDate
FROM #TempTable t1
GROUP BY corp, house, cust -- selecting distinct
```

So, my answer is to elimante the non-distinct column from the query by using sub queries.  There might be an easier way to do it though.  I'm curious to see what others post.

Sorry, i keep editing this, I keep trying to find ways to make it easier to show what I did.